# game of craps in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Still working on this, and I have no clue how to continue/ how to make it work. I need to figure out how to use canvas to display a clear output, which is currently not working at all. I know there are some problems with the code, but I don't have the knowledge to be able to address these problems and fix them, because I don't know where they are. I've been working for hours on it, just trying to change random things hoping something will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

<title>Game of Craps</title>
<script>
var roll1 = 0;
var roll2 = 0;
var lose = 0;
var win = 0;
var sumOfDice = 0;
var count = 0;

}
function play(){
    while (count < numOfGames){
        rollDice();
        count++

        sumOfDice = rollDice()


        switch (sumOfDice) {
            case 7: case 11:
                win++;
                break;
            case 2: case 3: case 12:
                lose++;
                break;
            default:
                var point = sumOfDice;
                sumOfDice = rollDice();

                while (point != sumOfDice){
                    if (sumOfDice == 7){
                        lose++;
                        break;
                    }
                    rollDice();
                    sumOfDice = roll1+roll2;
                    }

                if (point == sumOfDice) {
                    win++;
                }
                break;

        }
    }
}

function rollDice(){
    var roll1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    var roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1; 
    sumOfDice = roll1 + roll2;
    return sumOfDice;

function print(){
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "maroon";
    ctx.fillRect(300, 175, 200, 200);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font="100px Georgia";
    ctx.fillText(roll1, 350, 300)


    var d = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "maroon";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 175, 200, 200); 
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font="100px Georgia";
    ctx.fillText(roll2, 350, 300)

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My Game of Craps</h1>

<fieldset id="fieldset"> 
    <legend><div id="title">Rules:</div></legend>
        <p class="rules">1st roll:<br>
            2, 3, 12 are losers<br>
            7, 11 are winners<br>
            4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10 establish your point for the next roll<br><br>

            Next roll:<br>
            7 is a loser<br>
            Making your point (getting the same value as the first roll) is a winner<br>
            All other values require another roll of the dice</p>
</fieldset>

<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:5px solid navy blue;"> </canvas>

<input type="button" onclick="play()" value="Roll">


<script>
var ask = prompt("Do you want to play my game of craps? Answer yes or no", "yes")
    if (ask == "yes"){
        var numOfGames = prompt ("How many times do you wish to play?", "4")}
    else if (ask == "no"){
        document.write("Oh, well.")
    }

var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "maroon";
ctx.fillRect(300, 175, 200, 200);

var d = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "maroon";
ctx.fillRect(20, 175, 200, 200); 
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your Question is very vague... Did you try stepping through it step by step in debug mode? What exactly is your Question / Problem?

Comment: i don't think its so much of a bug problem. it's more of i literally don't know what i'm doing sort of problem

Comment: Problem is.. i also dont know what you are trying to do. :D Step by Step Debug should atleast help you to understand what your code currently is doing.

Comment: [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/JavaScript) and [JavaScript.com](https://www.javascript.com/)